# creating time series with seq and lubridate

Tags: r

Hi i have a data set with all character data type

```
col1        min_date        max_date
Minutes     2016-06-01    2016-06-27 11:15:00
15_minutes  2016-06-01    2016-06-27 11:15:00
```

Now i trying to make time series according to values in "col1"
for Minutes :

```
time_index <- seq(from = ymd(df$min_date), 
                  to = ymd_hms(df$max_date), by = "minute")
```

for 15_minutes :

```
time_index <- seq(from = ymd(df$min_date), 
                  to = ymd_hms(df$max_date), by = "15 minute")
```

**then i am getting error**

> Error in seq.Date(from = ymd(df$min_date), 
>                     to = ymd_hms(df$max_date), by = "minute",  : 
>     'from' must be of length 1

how do we solve ,thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `Map` to do this as `seq` is not vectorized to take multiple ranges of dates.  With `Map`, we specify the input arguments as the dataset columns in the same order as `from`, `to` and `by` and apply the `seq`.  The 'col1' substring is taken for the `by` argument

```
df1$col1 <-  sub("utes", "", sub("_", " ", tolower(df1$col1)))

lst <- Map(seq, as.POSIXct(df1$min_date), 
        as.POSIXct(df1$max_date), df1$col1)
lapply(lst, head, 2)
#[[1]]
#[1] "2016-06-01 00:00:00 IST" "2016-06-01 00:01:00 IST"

#[[2]]
#[1] "2016-06-01 00:00:00 IST" "2016-06-01 00:15:00 IST"
```

Comment: great & thanks , i am trying to make "lst" as data frame (df =as.data.frame(lst) ) throwing an error

Comment: @snr999 It won't work because the lengths might be different.  In the first case, you have by minutes, and in second case it is 15 minutes.  Let me know how you want the output

Comment: can we create 2 different data frame, i.e df_min is for min series and df_15mins is for 15 mins time series..?

Comment: @snr999 yes, you can do `d1 <- data.frame(Date = lst[[1]]); d2 <- data.frame(Date = lst[[2]])`

Comment: Perfect , Great akrun